# Linear Algebra and Linear Transformation of $T(A) = A^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am taking a linear algebra class in college. Linear algebra is very new to me.

One of the exercise problems is asking me to determine if $T(A) = A^2$ is a linear transformation, "Where T is a mapping whose domain is the vector space $M_{22}$".

My textbook shows examples using vectors but doesn't show how to handle vector spaces. I am suspecting the way to set this up is: $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ and use the $T(k\vec u) = kT(\vec u)$ and $T(\vec u+\vec v) = T(\vec u) + T(\vec v)$.

Could I get a little help with this.

Thanks in advanced for the help.

Comment: Hint: what is $T(kA)$?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, your vectors are the matrices.

Hence we are suppose to verify $$T\left(k A \right)=kT(A)$$

and $$T(A+B)=T(A)+T(B)$$

to check linearity. If one of these conditions fail, then it is not linear.

Guide:

Try to let the matrices be some special matrix to check if it is not linear. For example, try zero matrices and **identity** matrices. Try to let $k$ be $0$, positive, or **negative**.

To have an intuition of whether it is true or not. think of whether $x^2$ is a linear function for real number. While it is not a proof when you work with $\mathbb{R}$, it should give you ideas of how to construct counter examples.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't be a linear transformation as you can choose two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that they commute and $AB \not= 0$, the $T(A+B) = (A+B)^2 = A^2 + B^2 + 2AB \not= A^2 + B^2 = T(A) + T(B)$.